# Setting up a message after location change with UI-Router and AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I currently have a simple controller that checks to see if something is true or false.  If its false we send the user to a different page.  It looks a bit like this:

```
  if (ok === false){
    $location.path('/follow');
  }
  else
  {
  do stuff brah
  }
```

I'm using UI-Router ATM but I"m not sure if that matters.  What I'd like to happen is that if this gets fired, the follow page will display a message with something like "Hey we'd like you to fill this out before you go forward!"

However the tricky part is that if the user goes to **/follow** on their own in don't want any message to appear.  It should only happen if this if gets trigger on the controller from the other page.  Make sense?

Comment: So you want to share state between controllers? If so. The simplest solution would be to use a service. You can inject it into both controllers and write read values.

Comment: Kind of.  I want trigger a message to the user that is coming from one page to another based on this if/else statement.  Not if the person comes from one page and goes to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options.

Building a service and injecting it in the two controllers to store a variable is one.

You could also transmit the information in the url like so :

```
$location.path('/follow').search('showForm', 'true');
```

And then read the url when your /follow module is created :

```
if( $location.search().showForm === true ){
  // do the things brah
  $location.search('showForm', null);
}
```

You could also probably use the state change events from ui-router with fromParams and toParams to transmit the information : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki
I have never tried but it should work.